# How is assigning more efficient in Python and how does it work internally?

Tags: python

In Python is

```
a,b = b,a
```

more efficient than

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

?
How does that it work internally?

Comment: I would guess this is a place where efficiency is very unlikely to be the most important metric. Pick your efficiency battles.

Answer (score 2):

It's trivially faster as an implementation detail, but not enough to make a meaningful difference in most programs. It's faster because it avoids a `STORE`/`LOAD` pair of operations in favor of a `ROT_TWO` instruction, which is used after loading both source variables onto the program stack, to flip the order of the top two elements of the stack before `STORE`ing back normally.

As noted, the speed up is trivial (in a few trials, the swap was faster than the explicit temporary, but only by a matter of single digit nanoseconds, which almost never matters), but it's cleaner to read the obvious swap, so people tend to prefer it when it's needed.

For the internals, the `dis` module is helpful:

```
>>> import dis

>>> dis.dis('a, b = b, a')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              4 ROT_TWO
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis('temp = a; a = b; b = temp')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 STORE_NAME               1 (temp)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (temp)
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that the swap takes one fewer bytecode instructions, as well as executing more of the same instruction in a row (which may help cache utilization a tiny bit). The exact instructions differ based on where you execute it (`_NAME` might be `_FAST` or `_GLOBAL` or the like), so there might be more performance gains to be had when the instructions are more expensive (my microbenchmark was for function locals which use `_FAST` instructions that have the least overhead; running in global scope would probably make swapping a titch faster relatively speaking). But again, it's all trivial in the face of the choice of shorter, cleaner code vs. longer, uglier code.